# Binding a Kendo Gauge to local data

Tags: kendo-ui

In the Kendo documentation there are examples of binding many charts to local data, but there is nothing for the radial gauge.

Can anyone tell me how to specify the value for the pointer using an int in my controller?

```
<div id="gauge-container">
@(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
    .Name("gauge")
    .Pointer(pointer =>pointer.Value(intFromController) )
    .Scale(scale => scale
        .MinorUnit(5)
        .StartAngle(-30)
        .EndAngle(210)
        .Max(180)
    )
)
</div>
```

EDIT -- For anyone who arrives here with the same issue here is how I fixed it(actual code edited with test function to simplicity, also sorry for indenting, in a rush.):

**View:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: 'test/',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#gauge").data("kendoRadialGauge").value(data);
        }
    })



})</script>
```

```
@(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()

    .Name("gauge")
    .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(0))
    .Scale(scale => scale
        .MinorUnit(5)
        .StartAngle(-30)
        .EndAngle(210)
        .Max(180)
    )
)
```

**Controller**

```
public double test()
{
    double value = 10;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate you adding the closing </div>, doing so has removed the previous comments.. Is there a way to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

In Action of The Controller you can set:

```
ViewData["myAngle"] = 123;
```

And in View, you can use it in such way:

```
<div id="gauge-container">
@(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
    .Name("gauge")
    .Pointer(pointer =>pointer.Value(@ViewData["myAngle"]) )
    .Scale(scale => scale
        .MinorUnit(5)
        .StartAngle(-30)
        .EndAngle(210)
        .Max(180)
    )
)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error "cannot convert from object to double" even if I try and cast it as a double. I spoke to a colleague and I may have worded my post wrong too, what we need is a datasource bound to the gauge, and have the ability to refresh only this gauge and not the rest of the page periodically.